# What is the recommended touch screen displays for Rasp Pi 3 that work with Win IoT Core?

Tags: touchscreen

I bought [a small touch screen](https://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B01GFT8Y16/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) but it does not work with Windows 10 IoT Core. For those who know any touch screens that work with Windows 10 IoT Core, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The official Raspberry pi one should work.

Comment: Which is one...................................................?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-touch-display/